# android layout radiogroup position

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I have radiogroup :

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/overlay_2"
             android:id="@+id/rgSettings">`

             <RadioButton android:layout_width="140dp"
                          android:layout_height="100dp"
                          android:id="@+id/s_mph"
                          android:background="@drawable/settings_speed_mph"
                          android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"/>

             <RadioButton android:layout_width="140dp"
                          android:layout_height="100dp"
                          android:id="@+id/s_kph"
                          android:checked="false"
                          android:background="@drawable/settings_speed_kph"
                          android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                          android:layout_gravity="center"
                          android:gravity="right"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Link in screenshot : http://joxi.ru/A5GhUxjKTJBQH7uRaK4

(1) radiogroup 
(2) - (3) its radio buttons.
I need radibutton (2) set in position - left, radiobutton (3) set in right position. What do I need for this?

Add:
i need set first button set left position in radiogroup, secondary button set in right position radiogroup. Like This: joxi.ru/FqKhUxjKTJBsH5OWteQ

Answer (score 0):

Why You are setting the button that You need on the left side as first? Just switch it:

```
         <RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/overlay_2"
         android:id="@+id/rgSettings">

         <RadioButton android:layout_width="140dp"
                      android:layout_height="100dp"
                      android:id="@+id/s_kph"
                      android:checked="false"
                      android:background="@drawable/settings_speed_kph"
                      android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                      android:gravity="right"/>

         <RadioButton android:layout_width="140dp"
                      android:layout_height="100dp"
                      android:id="@+id/s_mph"
                      android:background="@drawable/settings_speed_mph"
                      android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"/>             

         </RadioGroup>
```

Also, You can play a little bit with the layout_margin attributes to make space between the buttons.

Comment: it didnt help me((
in left side i need button (mph) in right (kph)
and i need to use only radiobuttons

Comment: oh sorry i wrong. 
what i need ? i need set first button set left position in radiogroup, secondary button set in  right position radiogroup. Like This: 
http://joxi.ru/FqKhUxjKTJBsH5OWteQ

Comment: have you tested it? I think it would be good to show the complete layout file. If my example doesent work, there could be another layout that is causing this (where Your radiogroup is inside).